# Can't connect to "Jenkins-On-Azure"

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-virtual-machine

I created a Jenkins linux vm on Azure on a new resource group.

I followed the steps described here: 
[Create a Jenkins server on an Azure Linux VM from the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/install-jenkins-solution-template).

So I ran the command `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:8080:localhost:8080 jenkinsadmin@jenkins2517454.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`
 (changed the username and dns name to my own) on my linux vm and it seems fine (no errors).

Now whenever I try to connect from my own computer (not on azure) on port 8080 I get on the linux vm the following message: `channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed` and It doesn't let me log in into Jenkins.

How can it be solved?

Thank you

Comment: did you open port 8080 on the Network Security Group?

Comment: You should create ssh tunnle on your local VM. I notice that you create the tunnle on your linux VM, so you could not access it on your local computer.

Comment: The command `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:8080:localhost:8080 jenkinsadmin@jenkins2517454.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com` creates a SSH tunnle.

Comment: Also, you only create one ssh Tunnel. When you open the tunnle on linux VM, please exit it and re-open new Tunnel on your Window VM. After the tunnel is created. If you execute `netstat -ant|findstr 8080`, you will see like https://imgur.com/a/rp2Gq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a NSG issue. You don't need add port 8080 on Azure NSG rules.

If you want to connect from your computer with `http://localhost:8080/`, you should need create a [SSH tunnel on your local computer](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-with-putty/). You could do it with putty.

[image]

**Configure the Tunnel**

[image]

---

Also, you could install Linux on Windows. Please refer to the following steps:

1.Install [Linux on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

2.Open Power shell on execute `bash`

3.Execute `sudo -i` and `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:8080:localhost:8080 jenkinsadmin@jenkins2517454.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`

[image]

Now, I could access `http://localhost:8080/` on my local computer.(The default user name is admin).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to access from external network, you need to "**add inbound port rule**" as follows:

[image]

For more details, refer "[Create Jenkins server on an Azure Linux VM from the Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/install-jenkins-solution-template)".